# How to get an UI Picker within a web app?

Tags: html, user-interface

For people familiar with the iOS UIPicker, a date or number can be chosen from that kind of wheel. A user can drag up or down by touch to increase or decrease value.

I want to reproduce the same behaviour on a web app used on mobile devices, like iPads, Windows Surface, etc. The web app is using HTML5 (and AngularJS as front-end framework).

Any existing component out there for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the client's browser to decide how to display html5 ui elements such as datepicker's and spin boxes.

Please see the following examples: 
http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

If you would like to have greater control and consistency you might consider using a library like jQueryUi